# Shortcut to a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

This is a little pathetic :) but I cannot figure it out:

I want to create a windows batch file that calls another one without opening a new console window. It's used to fire up the glassfish, but that's secondary.

My batch file "start.bat" reads

```
@echo off
cd bin
call "asadmin.bat start-domain domain1"
pause
```

And I want to call it from the windows console. Unfortunately it only opens up a new console window without doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
@echo off
cd bin
call asadmin.bat start-domain domain1
pause
```

the "" can lead batch to seek for the batch file "asadmin.bat start-domain domain1"

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't make any difference ... :(

Comment: That one came packaged with glassfish, and it works when I call it directly with the given command.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
@ ECHO OFF
cd bin
COMMAND /C asadmin.bat start-domain domain1
```

note that using this command starts up a new environment which inherits any variables from the calling batch file.